# Windows CMD command: on which Windows versions does it work?

Tags: windows

I am looking for a program that can take a Windows CMD command line, e.g.:

- `Forfiles /p " C:\Backups\SQL " /d -6 /c "CMD /C del @FILE"`

and outputs on which Windows the command work works. In this example, [Forfiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forfiles) first became available in the Windows Vista, so the output would be Windows Vista/7/8.

If possible, free, works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, can be called from another program, can analyze several commands at once and can analyze an entire .bat file.